# Changing detail in splitviewcontroller using storyboards

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, storyboard, xamarin

I've been going around in circles for hours. I have a Xamarin storyboard application, where I have a container view which I have embedded a split view controller in. I am trying to change the detail view based on the user selection on the table. In my table ViewController I have:

```
    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad ();

        string[] tableItems = new string[] {"Vegetables","Fruits","Flower Buds","Legumes","Bulbs","Tubers"};
        this.TableView.Source = new TableSource (tableItems, this);
        this.TableView.AllowsSelection = true;
        this.TableView.ReloadData();

    }
```

And then in my table source I have the following which should change the detail. Note that `viewController1` is the table view controller, passed to it when setting the source.

```
    public override void RowSelected (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {

        new UIAlertView("Row Selected", tableItems[indexPath.Row], null, "OK", null).Show();
        tableView.DeselectRow (indexPath, true); // iOS convention is to remove the highlight

        viewController1.ParentViewController.PerformSegue("DetailSegue", viewController1.ParentViewController);

    }
```

I have created a segue from my split view controller to my detail view controller called DetailSegue, and this is what I am calling. This errors, but either way I don't think calling a segue is the correct way.

I have also tried:

```
viewController1.ParentViewController[1] = new TestDetailViewController();
```

But as I am using storyboard the `TestDetailViewController` method expects intPtr handle and I'm not sure how to reference this. The Xamarin recipe for split view controllers isn't using storyboards, and I can't find the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You might try modifying the navigation controller's stack...something like this (translated with limited Xamarin knowledge)...

```
public override void RowSelected (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath) {

UINavigationController navController = self.splitViewController.viewControllers.lastObject;

NSArray newStack = new NSArray.arrayWithObjects(newController, nil);

navController.setViewControllers(newStack);

}
```

Again, I'm rusty on the .NET...here is the Objective-C from which I translated...

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

UINavigationController *navController = [[[self splitViewController] viewControllers] lastObject]
NSArray *newStack = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:newController, nil ];
[navController setViewControllers:newStack];

}
```

Source: http://www.dharmaworks.net/Consulting/switching-detail-views-in-uisplitviewcontroller-with-ios7